# Why does the closure executed in .map not change the captured value?

Tags: rust

Here is my code:

```
let mut v = Vec::new();
let _ = (0..5).map(|i| v.push(i));

println!("{:?}", v);   //output: []
```

The captured value is `v`. I expect the code above to print `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, but it prints `[]`.

Why is that?

Comment: The compiler warning that `a` is unused should be a clue that you're not doing something right. [If you remove `a` entirely, you get a more descriptive message that should point you in the right direction.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=701fc9dae1aca1ad89db47684d2b0804)

Comment: Not addressing the question itself directly, but looking at the code, why not just do `let v: Vec<_> = Vec::from_iter(0..5);`? (which needs `use std::iter::FromIterator;`)

Comment: @SirDarius Thanks. This is just a piece of code to demonstrate the problem. We usually don't use it that way.

Comment: @trentcl I've changed `a` to `_` to avoid this compiler warning.

Answer (score 0):

The `map` method does not iterate through elements immediately. Instead, it creates a lazy iterator which you can use later. One of the ways to force the new iterator to perform its job is the `Iterator::collect` method. In your case, it will produce a new collection filled with empty values (`()` because it's the type of `v.push(i)`):

```
let mut v = Vec::new();
let v2: Vec<()> = (0..5).map(|i| v.push(i)).collect();
println!("{:?}", v); //output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This does excess work by creating the vector `v2`. Try to avoid such inefficient operations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem was solved. Maybe I'd better to read [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-02-iterators.html) again :)

Comment: "One of the ways to force the new iterator to perform its job is the `Iterator::collect`" which is probably the worst way to do that if you don't care about the result.